# What's the difference between "onto" and "on"

Tags: prepositions, word-difference

Are they near synonyms? I always thought that they pretty much meant the same thing, meaning you could always replace "onto" with "on" without meaningfully changing the meaning of a sentence.

Consider these two sentences:

> I rested my head onto the tree.
>
> I rested my head on the tree.

It's pretty much the same, right?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, not the same.  Resting your head on a tree is fine, but "I rested my head onto the tree." is not idiomatic.

"Onto" implies something in **motion** toward the place that it will be "on" (when it gets there).

> The magazines were *on* the table.
>
> I dumped the magazines *onto* the table.

Or

> Snow was *on* the trees.
>
> Snow fell *onto* the trees.

In fact, "I rested my head onto the tree." suggests a vague idea that it might be painful (because of the motion toward the tree).

Comment: +1, though the OP is basically right that you can usually replace "onto" with "on". The only problem with his/her example is that it's one where "onto" isn't an option! (Your first *onto* example would become ambiguous with *on* -- "I dumped the magazines on the table" can also mean "I discarded the magazines that had been on the table" -- but it would still be correct with the intended meaning. Your second *onto* example would be absolutely perfect with *on*; "Snow fell onto the trees" and "Snow fell on the trees" are synonymous in any plausible context that I can think of.)

Comment: Well, right, I guess "on" can often replace "onto", but not the other way around (can't use "onto" with something stationary "on" something), so "onto" & "on" aren't synonyms.

Comment: To me, the "rest my head onto the tree" version possibly implies that you did so by first removing it from your shoulders...

Answer (score 5):

No, not the same. Here's a couple of sentences which are both meaningful, but mean different things.

> I jumped onto the trampoline.

Previously, I was not on the trampoline. I jumped, and I landed on the trampoline.

> I jumped on the trampoline.

I was already on the trampoline. I jumped and landed on the trampoline again.

Answer (score 4):

*Onto* can also be used in its open form, where it is *on to*. It is normally used with the following sense of [*on*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on) in the case of physical activity of the kind you describe:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **1 a** —used as a function word to indicate position in contact with and supported by the top surface of
>   // the book is lying *on* the table

When using *onto* in this sense, you are denoting a sense of motion, where something is moved to be in contact with the *top surface* of something.

---

But when simply using just *on* with a verb that describes physical action, it generally means *against*, in the second sense of *on*:

> **1 b** —used as a function word to indicate position in or in contact with an outer surface
>   // the fly landed *on* the ceiling
>   // I have a cut *on* my finger
>   // paint *on* the wall

In these examples, the outer surface of something *can* be top, bottom, or side. But context will determine the direction.

---

Therefore, consider the difference between the following two sentences:

> I leaned **on** the door.

This is the equivalent of saying that you leaned *against* the door. Your entire body, from feet to head, could be connected with the vertical surface of the door.

> I jumped **onto** the door.

This is the equivalent of saying that you jumped across or down from somewhere else, and ended up with your feet, or other parts of your body, in contact with the *top* of the door.

Or, possibly, the door is not attached to a door frame, but is lying flat on the floor. In that case, you jumped on top of its horizontal surface—something that, because of gravity, is not possible when it's in an upright position.

If somebody runs and jumps, causing their feet to contact the vertical surface of an attached door, we would still not say that they jumped *onto* the door, we would say that they jumped *into* the door.)

---

Let's go back to your original sentences, and looking at them in reverse order.

> I rested my head **on** the tree.

This would normally indicate that you placed your head against the tree *trunk*, or against the *side* of the tree.

> I rested my head **onto** the tree.

This sounds strange and is not something that would normally be used. The reason for this is that *onto* still has the equivalent interpretation of *I jumped onto the door*.

In other words, what this *suggests* is one of two things:

1. You climbed to the *top* of the tree and then rested your head against its upper branches.
2. You jumped from one tree to another, or were dropped from above, and ended up on top of the tree, where you rested your head against its upper branches.

We would likely not interpret it this way (because it wouldn't make sense) but we would still feel there was something off about the sentence.

*Onto* is not normally used with *rested* or *leaned*. And it's not used because of this strange association.

In describing something *resting* or *leaning*, we would either say *on* or *against*, not *onto*.